# having a trouble numbering in wordpress pages

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Hi there I use this function for numbering pagination on wordepress.

```
function numbering_pagination() {
    global $wp_query;
    $all_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
    if ($all_pages > 1) {
        return paginate_links(array(
            'base'       => get_pagenum_link() . '%_%',
            'format'     => '?paged=%#%',
            'current'    => $current_page,
            'mid_size'   => 1,
            'max_size'   => 1,
            'type'       => 'list',
            'next_text'  => __('next'),
            'prev_text'  => __('prev')
        ));
    }
}
```

and is Work well with (index, category). but in page search, the permalink show like this when I click next button.first ckick like this.

```
 exmp.com/?s?paged=2
```

secend click.

```
exmp.com/?s?paged=2?paged=2
```

PLZ enyone HElp

Comment: What is `get_pagenum_link() ` returning? Like what is that exact value?

Comment: This link may help. Look at the base that they use https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/139804

Comment: get_pagenum_link() . is function in woredpress 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pagenum_link/

Comment: The base URL is not set correctly it should be something like this `/` and the page and then the URL params